# Increasing the "bit depth" of a one hot encoded variable in a time series in R

Tags: r

I am working with frame by frame video data in tabular format. When an event happens, it is only coded for that single frame. I would like to order events in pseudotime and there is no distinct periodicity to them. Regular one-hot encoding does not encode the 'eventness' of timestamps within close proximity to the frame labeled "hey stuff happens here". I imagine that this could be modeled as a sinusoidal function, convolved with the the initial array that represents a column. This way, even when frames are not ordered, I can still see the 'eventness' of each one.

I was thinking something along these lines:

```r
x <- c(...0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0...)

y <- c(...0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0...)

(convolve(x, y))
```

I am struggling with designing a for loop that might do this for each column of dummy variables.

Also, I am using "bit depth" as an analogy, since this is like increasing the bit depth of an audio sample. Basically, I want to trade in my NES for a Sega Genesis.

Thanks!

Comment: To the bevy of people on the edge of their seats, I ended up using a moving average to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

To the bevy of people on the edge of their seats, I ended up using a moving average to solve this problem.